# Windows Datacenter 2008 recovery ISO

Tags: windows-server-2008

I am using virtualBox with windows datacenter to play around with some web development.

The last time I had to shut down the computer, it installed an update and shut down normally.

When I rebooted, it started doing a checkdisk and processed a bunch of files (from hard poweroffs before mabey).

Now when I start, I get a bluescreen of death every time it loads (Safe mode,etc)

I have googled around for a boot / recovery disk, but can't seem to find one for datacenter.

Cheers
-Will

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried booting of your media and choosing the recovery option? I believe this option should still be available on your media as it would contain all 2008 product editions but possibly just pre-pidded to a specific version install.

Ok, I just used Windows 2008 DataCenter R1.

1. Boot from CDROM
2. Entering your language preference
3. At the Install Now screen I selected Repair your computer down the bottom left
4. Click next after it has found your installation
5. Use the Windows PC Restore if you have been using windows backup

If you have not been using windows backup and you have no backups at all, you can try any restore mediums that support repairing NTFS filesystems or click Command Prompt and do a chkdsk c: to try and recover